# If I sell my iPad, is erase/reset enough or do I need to sign-out first?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, secure-erase

I gave my iPad to someone else, I used the erase function and when I turn it on it shows as default, to select language and connect to a wifi, etc.

But the [apple article page about this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351), says to use sign-out first, and then erase.

Will there be a problem if I didn't sign-out first ? In a way that ... could my email/account/name show up on the screen when new user sets it up ?

I deleted the device from my iCloud account too. After I erased it.

Comment: Does the iPad still show up in "Find my device" on iCloud.com?

Comment: No, it is not under "find my devices", I know I seen it under my iCloud account (after erasing it), but I deleted it from there. Now I don't see it anywhere in iCloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did a factory reset (Settings > General > Reset < [Erase All Content and Settings](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/ipad/ipad8f91b5e3/14.0/ipados/14.0)) it asked you for your AppleID password at that point, right?

That should, while factory resetting, dis-associate your AppleID.  If you're seeing the "Hello" welcome initial start-up screen, you should be good.

Comment: you should turn off Find My first as that disables iCloud activation.

Comment: @NathanEllis The _Erase All Content and Settings_ option includes turning off Find My as part of its set of tasks before fully wiping the device. It's not necessary to turn off Find My as a separate step.

Comment: I do not remember manually doing a remove of `find my` during reset/erase, if it did that, it did it automatically as part of these steps. I did manually removed the device from my iCloud devices list, using iCloud website.

Answer (score 1):

Prior if I recall correctly iOS 9, e.g iOS 7 and 8 you had to sign out, and then wipe all settings as *Find my Device* was still left active if you don't.

Since iOS 9 and later Reset all Settings signs you out of iCloud and also asks to disable *Find my Device*, but you will still see the device on icloud.com web or in your iCloud profile. This does not affect device it self, but it can still use amount of paired devices for Apple Store and Apple Music.
So if you want fully remove device from your account, which you sell, just delete it from your Devices in icloud.com

[image: Account Settings]

[image: My Devices]